# Check frequence of ocurrences in each subitem in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, frequency

I have an array that returns something like:

```
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "5ac2f57f-61cf-454b-9457-484b8484c1d3",
        "userID": "7d21e968-f32a-4cb9-a0db-dd98d1d2973a",
        "tag": "REPORT_CREATE",
    },
    {
        "id": "3d302f03-75da-40cf-8b86-d9673fdc3b4a",
        "userID": "1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda",
        "tag": "REPORT_CREATE",
    },
]
```

And i need to return the frequence of the "userID", but as you can see, it is a subitem.

So if i do something like:

```
function getOccurrence(array, value) {
   var count = 0;
   array.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
   return count;
}

console.log(getOccurrence(arr, "userIDsomething"));
```

That wouldn't do cause the `userID` would have to be the objects itself, not inside [0], [1] and so on. But i am stuck there. Any suggestions?

Comment: `array.forEach((v) => (v.userID === value && count++));`, but you could also pass a property to your function to make it more reusable. `getOccurrence(array, value, prop) {...` and then `array.forEach((v) => ((prop ? v[prop] : v) === value && count++));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to compare `value` against the `userID` property of the items in your array, rather than against the items themselves. Also, it might simplify your code to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Try this:

```
function getOccurrence(array, value) {
   return array.filter((v) => v.userID === value).length;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the `value` with the object which will never be equal, You have to compare the `value` with its `userID`, using `v.userID` as

```
array.forEach((v) => v.userID === value && count++);
```

**1)** You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.userID === value ? ++acc : acc), 0)
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "5ac2f57f-61cf-454b-9457-484b8484c1d3",
    userID: "7d21e968-f32a-4cb9-a0db-dd98d1d2973a",
    tag: "REPORT_CREATE",
  },
  {
    id: "3d302f03-75da-40cf-8b86-d9673fdc3b4a",
    userID: "1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda",
    tag: "REPORT_CREATE",
  },
];

function getOccurrence(array, value) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.userID === value ? ++acc : acc), 0);
}

console.log(getOccurrence(arr, "1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda"));
```

**2)** You can get occurrences using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as

```
arr.filter((o) => o.userID === value).length
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "5ac2f57f-61cf-454b-9457-484b8484c1d3",
    userID: "7d21e968-f32a-4cb9-a0db-dd98d1d2973a",
    tag: "REPORT_CREATE",
  },
  {
    id: "3d302f03-75da-40cf-8b86-d9673fdc3b4a",
    userID: "1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda",
    tag: "REPORT_CREATE",
  },
];

function getOccurrence(array, value) {
  return arr.filter((o) => o.userID === value).length;
}

console.log(getOccurrence(arr, "1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers your problem lies in comparing a string value to each iterated object instead of the to the relevant property of the object. To fix it you should simply access the `useID` in your comparison.

```
array.forEach((v) => (v.userID === value && count++));
```

Other than that your method is fine, and doesn't suffer the side effect of creating a new array as the `filter().length` shortcut does.

But hardcoding the `userID` into what looks like a utility function doesn't make much sense, so instead you can accept a third `property` parameter in your your function to specify the property to compare against. Here using a `for...of` instead of `forEach()` and checking if the `property` is passed and if not just comparing directly.

```js
const arr = [{'id': '5ac2f57f-61cf-454b-9457-484b8484c1d3','userID': '7d21e968-f32a-4cb9-a0db-dd98d1d2973a','tag': 'REPORT_CREATE',},{'id': '3d302f03-75da-40cf-8b86-d9673fdc3b4a','userID': '1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda','tag': 'REPORT_CREATE',},];

function getOccurrence(array, value, prop) {
  let count = 0;
  for (const v of array) {
    (prop !== undefined ? v[prop] : v) === value && count++;
  }

  return count;
}

const count = getOccurrence(arr, '1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda', 'userID');

console.log('1dafdb46-a49e-4194-9e5b-9c44be7e4cda: ', count);
```